# Periodically check an element of a web page

Tags: php, javascript

How to implement a web service that periodically checks if an element of a web page (say, `<div id="contentlist">`) has changed; then if there is a change, send a notification to an email address?

**Update**

There is one issue. The web page is dynamically generated, so if I look at the HTML source, there is nothing in the targe element.

And I want to implement this as a web service. Can I do that in cron?

Comment: What kind of element are you speaking about?

Comment: If the element is dynamically generated then hasn't it "changed" every time the page is requested? What if it generates different content for different users depending on some condition(s) such that for one user the generated content is always the same, while for another user it is always different?

Comment: @nnnnnn the element lists the contents from their database. If there is no new record, the element won't be changed. So I just need to get the name of all the contents, and compare with what I got last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab), create a script that checks if an element of a web page has changed (e.g. with `DOMDocument`) and that shoots you an email if so and then you set it up with a cron interval so you can define how often you want to have that checked. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [Cron Jobs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/)?